# Trying to skip empty tags beautifulsoup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read a page with python and print each element for the ratings. I've got a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` error and I don't understand how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
rating = movie.find('td', class_='ratingColumn imdbRating').strong.text
if rating:
    try:
        print(rating)
    except AttributeError:
        print("no rating")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check for "NoneType" before printing .text

```
rating = movie.find('td', class_='ratingColumn imdbRating').strong

if rating:
    print(rating.text)
else:
    print("no rating")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check `None Type` as below:

```
rating = movie.find('td', class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").strong

if rating is not None:
    rating = rating.text
else:
    rating = "No Rating"
```